# Function on compact set does not expands distance

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I have the following question.

Let $K$ be compact subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$. Prove that there does not exists any continuous $f: K \rightarrow K$ which expands distance i.e. $\forall x,y \in K$ $|f(x)-f(y)| > |x-y|.$

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: the function $(x,y) \mapsto |x-y|$ attains its maximum on $K \times K$.  Also, you don't have to assume that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Sorry. But Can you please elaborate it? Looking for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I think that hint is as much as I'm willing to share, until you show some further evidence of effort on your part.  I'm not going to just give you the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Define $g:K\times K$ by $g(x,y)=\left \| x-y \right \|$.

As $g$ is continuous, and $K\times K$ is compact, there is an $(x_0,y_0)\in K\times K$ such that $g(x_0,y_0)=\left \| x_0-y_0 \right \|$ is a maximum.

But then, since by hypothesis, $(f(x_0),f(y_0))\in K\times K$ we have

$\left \| \frac{f(x_0)-f(y_0)}{x_0-y_0} \right \|\leq 1\Rightarrow \left \| f(x_0)-f(y_0) \right \|\leq \left \| x_0-y_0 \right \|$

Comment: Can we do the problem using sequential argument?

Comment: Can you give an answer of the question using sequential criteria.